# List shows empty on Razor Pages, while it is full

Tags: c#, asynchronous, razor-pages

I'm getting some data from a API from which i create a List, however when i try to loop through the list in the .cshtml file it shows nothing and the count of the list is 0. But when i loop through the list in the OnGetAsync() method it does shows results.

I've tried it without the async on and i tried to fill the list within the getDataAsync() method.

```cs
        public IList<Employee> Employee = new List<Employee>();

        public async void OnGetAsync()
        {
            // Sets up HttpClient
            await RunAsync();

            // API call method which returns a list filled with the results
            Employee = await GetDataAsync("api-url");

            // Shows Results!
            foreach (var item in Employee)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(item.name);
            }
        }
```

```
static async Task<List<Employee>> GetDataAsync(string path)
        {
            string data = null;
            List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(path);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            JObject json = JObject.Parse(data);

            // Get the only the data i need from the entire json api result
            foreach (var d in json["data"])
            {
                string setId;
                string setName;
                string setUrl;


                if (d["id"] == null)
                {
                    setId = "NA";
                } else
                {
                    setId = d["id"].ToString();
                }

                if (d["person"]["full_name"] == null)
                {
                    setName = "NA";
                } else
                {
                    setName = d["person"]["full_name"].ToString();
                }

                if (d["avatar"]["url_small"] == null)
                {
                    setUrl = "NA";
                } else
                {
                    setUrl = d["avatar"]["url_small"].ToString();
                }

                list.Add(new Employee
                {
                    id = setId,
                    name = setName,
                    avatar_url = setUrl
                });
            }
            Debug.Unindent();
            return list;
        }
```

```html
        <!-- Shows 0 -->
        <p>@Model.Employee.Count</p>
        <!-- Shows nothing -->
        @foreach (var item in Model.Employee)
        {
           <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.name)</p>
        }
```

I expect to be able to loop through the list and showing results on the webpage, instead the count for the list is on 0 and it shows nothing.

Comment: A side note, `OnGetAsync` should return a `Task` not `void` because it's an async method

Comment: @Ammar Yup, that was it. Small thing to overlook. Make it an answer and i will check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is that `OnGetAsync` is an async method, which should return a `Task`, while you're returning `void`

Just change the return type of it.

```
public async Task OnGetAsync() 
{
    // Your code here
}
```